# Need example of Java Client Destop App consuming Two-way SSL Secured webservice

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jboss, two-way

I'm looking for an example of a java desktop application that consumes a Two-way SSL secured web service.   Any tutorials or examples would be great, especially if they are based on the Eclipse IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you're not familiar with SSL, (self-signed) certificates, keytool, key store, trust store, in one word PKI, I'd suggest to start with [The Fifteen Minute Guide to Mutual Authentication](http://monduke.com/2006/06/04/the-fifteen-minute-guide-to-mutual-authentication/) and [Java Secure HTTP Client Key Management](http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/java-secure-http-keys/). These resources are just **awesome** and should help you to get started and to understand what you'll need on the server side and the client side (and why).

Then, I suggest to check [Mutual Authentication for Web Services: A Live Example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/mutual-auth-141794.html).

And for the JBoss specific setup, check out the [SSLSetup](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/sslsetup) page of the JBoss wiki (more precisely the Authentication scenario #4).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, an actual applications that communicates via SSL to a web service provider?  SOAPui is right up your alley then - except it's a general-purpose web-service tester and not some domain-specific application.

And it's not eclipse based, although there is a SOAPui Eclipse plugin.